# Security of Time Machine's AFP connection

Tags: macos, security, time-machine, afp, man-in-the-middle

I use Time Machine to backup my Mac over the Internet on a Synology server. TM connects throught AFP protocol, it this protocol resistent to Man-in-the middle attack (attacker can't steal creditials or gain access to a volume)? Does TM adding some security improvements (like checking server's identity)?

If this use-case is not good idea, what are alternatives? (TM over Internet.)